# Создание и подключение библиотеки классов C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

Всем привет, при создании мной dll в C#, если я копирую код из своего заранее заготовленного класса в сгенерированный при создании класс и переименовываю его через обозреватель решений, то dll хорошо подключается к основному проекту. Но если я удаляю сгенерированный класс и подключаю свой через добавление существующего элемента к dll, то при добавлении dll в основной проект он ее просто не видит, хотя ссылки прописал так же. Проблема, вероятно, в том, что в том классе пространство имен другое, простое переименование его не помогает. Кто знает как решить проблему?

Comment: "Но если я удаляю сгенерированный класс и подключаю свой через добавление существующего элемента к dll, то при добавлении dll в основной проект он ее просто не видит" - проиллюстрируйте как-нибудь что-ли, а то не понятно что вы делаете и как. Опишите последовательность ваших действий по пунктам: 1)..., 2)..., и т.д.

Comment: `Проблема, вероятно, в том, что в том классе пространство имен другое` Вы не уверены, что у вас другой неймспейс? Приведите конкретные примеры что у вас в первом неймсейсе, что во втором. Если не уверены, где смотрится неймспейс -- то показывайте файлы целиком.